# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) When trying to read SQL Table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I am trying to get some data out of my SQL Table with this servlet and output it in a JSP file.
I found some articles with similar problems to mine but none of them helped in my case. I Hoped someone here can help me.

I have to do this Project for one of my classes. I am basically programming an online shop for Clothing. If I click on for example t-shirts, I want this code to put out all data it can find under the sql table "t-shirts" into a JSP file.

From what i learned from other peoples mistakes is that my SQL Query is wrong. But i dont understand why it marks me line 39 as false When I call the Method display().

So Here is my Code:

```
    @WebServlet("/DisplayClothes")
    public class DisplayClothes extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public DisplayClothes() {
        super();

    }
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/MySqlThidbDS")
    private DataSource ds;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<Clothes> Clothes= display();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("Clothes", Clothes);

        final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("./JSP/ViewColthing.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    public List<Clothes> display() throws ServletException{


        List<Clothes> cl = new ArrayList<Clothes>();

        try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
                 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM clothes")) {

            pstmt.setInt(1, 1);

            try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {

                while (rs.next()) { 

                    Clothes clothes= new Clothes(); 
                    clothes.setId(Long.valueOf(rs.getInt("id")));
                    clothes.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    clothes.setDes(rs.getString("description"));
                    clothes.price(rs.getFloat("preis"));
                    clothes.setSize(rs.getString("sizes"));
                    clothes.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));



                    cl.add(Clothes);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return cl;
        }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And I get This Error message.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at Servlets.DisplayClothes.display(DisplayClothes.java:76)
    at Servlets.DisplayClothes.doGet(DisplayClothes.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no bind parameters in your query. Remove

```
pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
```

There is nothing to set. Also,

```
cl.add(Clothes);
```

should be

```
cl.add(clothes);
```

Comment: I left the first one in by accident. I just tried a lot of stuff and left it in accidentaly. And the second one is with a small c. I just accidentaly Wrote it as a C as i translated the words I didnt write in english. I Removed pstmt.setInt(1, 1); but i get The same Error.

Comment: Recompile and redeploy. That error is exactly because you are trying to bind a parameter in query without a bind parameter.

Comment: Oh man i forgot to redeploy. Had some issues after this. But this solved my Problem for sure. Thanks a lot!